# Android error when getting password edit text value

Tags: android, android-edittext, passwords, tostring

I'm getting the password-edit-text value but I don't get what I want.

my code in getting the value:

```
String username = "", password = "";
username = ((EditText)findViewById(R.id.username_pet)).toString();
password = ((EditText)findViewById(R.id.password_pet)).toString();
```

but when I put the result to Toast I don't get it right. What I get is [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E0urf.png)
error.

any help will be much appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
username = ((EditText)findViewById(R.id.username_pet)).getText().toString();
password = ((EditText)findViewById(R.id.password_pet)).getText().toString();
```

Answer (score 1):

Your code would return you the id of your `EditText` yet what you want is the Text.
Try this

Replace this by :

```
 username = ((EditText)findViewById(R.id.username_pet)).toString();
 password = ((EditText)findViewById(R.id.password_pet)).toString();
```

**this**

```
username = ((EditText)findViewById(R.id.username_pet)).getText();
password = ((EditText)findViewById(R.id.password_pet)).getText();
```

Hope this helps

Comment: and have to add .toString() it solves my problem. Thanks

Comment: yeah welcome just updated it.Please mark it as correct if it helps and visit this for further details. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5028466/reading-text-of-an-edittext-in-android

Comment: Hey can I ass 1 more I can't post another question just yet, so I get the username and password and this

     public void login(String username, String password) {

        if(username == "user123" && password == "pass123") {
            toastShowMsg("Logged in");
        }

        else {
            toastShowMsg("Invalid username or password");
        }
    }

and it seems that I always end up in the "else" even if I got the right condition in the "if". I don't know whats wrong. Please help thanks

Comment: try to use String handling functions. and yes u can.

Comment: e.g `if(username.equals("user123") && password.equals("pass123")){ //todo stuff} else{//stuffs}`

Comment: Oh yea it works! :) Thanks man. Do you mind explaining to me whats the difference between .equals() and ordinary == in a if condition? I just want to understand if its okay to you. Thanks for the help man!

Comment: Yeah of course i mind my answer not being placed as the correct answer :). equals() are some string handling function specially built to handle strings in java.

Comment: I'm sorry about that but I find Mohammad answer more accurate when it comes in code line itself. But all of the answer here is correct in a way. Btw thanks for the explanation. :)

Answer (score 0):

This is happening because you are attempting to convert to string before getting the text of the input field. The app is doing exactly what you are telling it to do: Getting the EditText View and converting the View to a string, just not the text within the view. If that makes sense.

Try

```
EditText userName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.username_pet);
String userNameFromEditText = (String) username.getText().toString();
```

Then toast the value of userNameFromEditText.

Comment: Oh yeah I got the idea. Thanks much! Solves my problem.